# Can you write if ( (x && y) || y || z) { do this;}?

Tags: c#

Newbie question: In C#, how do I put a set of conditions, and one of them must be two values or conditions that are true together, not just one of them. For example, is the following valid syntax:

```
if ( (x && y) || y || z) { do this;}
```

Comment: Why don't you just try compiling the program yourself? :)

Comment: First of all, you could've just tried it and the compiler would tell you easily enough if it was valid syntax. Secondly, yes, you can do that. That is valid syntax. I would ask you to consider writing the code slightly different though, give the expression a name, store it into a local variable, that way it is easier to read the code later, when you don't have to guess why those expressions was checked. ie. something like this: `bool canSaveToDisk = (x && y) || y || z; if (canSaveToDisk) { do this; }`

Comment: How do I put a set of conditions where? One of the conditions must be two values? Unless they are boolean values... Can you please rephrase your question in English? We can't read your mind.

Comment: I don't really understand why people are answering this question...

Comment: @GrantWinney Actually, the purpose is to pass the condition check if Y, alone, is true, or X and Y together are true, but NOT if X, alone, is true. That's why Y is added to X, but it can still pass by itself. Makes sense now?

Comment: I have NO idea why people are trolling this question with down votes. A sane person just game the perfect answer to a newbie. So why the hate? Jeez, maybe I chose the programmming language with the very wrong community!

Comment: Just wanted to know if it's correct syntax to put the parentheses () WITHIN the parentheses. I understand now I can. The other part is how to check for: both x and y to be true, or y alone to be true, or z alone to be true? I understand that the above is ineffective in checking for the truth of x when accompanied by the truth of y. I want to check for the truth of x with all the above.

Comment: instead of complaining about down votes and critical questions you should try to clarify what you are trying to do. add you put your question it does not make any sense to test x if y or z are enough for the whole condition. if x is important for you in any other way you should give us the context instead of expecting us to guess what you want. and a syntax check is faster and easier with a compiler instead of a q&a website.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is valid syntax provided all the identifiers involved are `bool` identifiers, meaning a local variable, a parameter, a constant, field or a property that holds a `bool` value. If they're not, then no, that is not legal syntax.

I am also only referring to this part:

```
if ( (x && y) || y || z) { do this;}
^----------------------^
```

The last part: `{ do this; }` is *not* legal syntax but I understood your question to not be about that part.

Specifically, your whole statement says this:

- Either `x && y` has to be true
- Or `y` has to be true
- Or `z` has to be true

If any of those holds, then "do this", whatever that may be.

Now, let's analyze your expression a little further.

Since `y` stands alone, there seems to be little point in involving `x`.

Let's look at this expression: `(x && y) || y` and look at the possible values of `x` and `y` and the result:

```
   x   |   y   |   result  |  why?
---------------------------------------------
 false | false | false     | because neither x nor y is true
 false | true  | true      | because y is true: ... ? || y
 true  | false | false     | because y has to be true either way
 true  | true  | true      | because y is true: ... ? || y
```

Basically, you can remove `x` altogether, it has no bearing on the results (see my extra comment below though).

Your final statement could thus be this:

```
if (y || z) { do this; }
```

Now, having said all of that, here's one additional thing. I am also assuming that `x`, `y` and `z` are placeholders for something else. What if `x` was a method? Would it matter then?

Yes, because to know the result of `x()` the method would have to be called. If calling the method has side-effects beyond just returning `true` or `false` then you may very well *not* want to simply remove it. The final result of the expression is not going to depend on the value of `x`, but the side-effects might be warranted either way. Questionable design perhaps, but that's hard to tell without something more specific.

Comment: if `y` has to be true, it makes no sense to check for `x && y` aswell (unless `x` has side effects, but that'd be weird :-) ). But this is the right answer, +1

Comment: I wasn't finished posting my answer. Please re-read my now updated answer and see if there are things missing now.

Comment: Lasse, thank you very much. That's exactly what I wanted to know. I don't know why people are trolling with down votes.

@Jcl Actually, the purpose is to pass the condition check if Y, alone, is true, or X and Y together are true, but NOT if X, alone, is true. That's why Y is added to X, but it can still pass by itself. Makes sense now?

Comment: Yes, but still, X does not matter. If Y is true, it does not matter in the slightest whether X is true or false.

Comment: @Lasse much better now :-)

Comment: It is ( x && y), Lasse. Am I missing something?

Comment: If your question is really "how do I write an expression that does ***" then you need to explain what you want to do. The code is legal syntax, assuming the assumptions I laid out in my answer. If you want it to do something else, you must explain that something else.

Comment: @Rok *"pass if Y is true but X is false"* or *"pass if Y is true and X is true"*, but never *"if Y is false"*... that's the same as saying *"pass if Y is true"* (or *"don't pass if Y is false"*), you don't care about whether `X` is true or false, you only care about `Y`

Comment: Ohhhh, the condition will pass if Y is true because of the || y ||, and will not pass if it's false because y is checked with x. I got it now. I guess a second part of my question has arisen now: How do I check whether x is true and only pass when y is true, too?

Comment: `if(x && y)` means that both x and y need to be true. if you need both x and y to be true -or- z to be true, then `if((x && y) || z)`. Just read it loud :-)

Comment: And yes, knowing that the brackets WITHIN the brackets is legal syntax answered my question. This new confusing mix of conditions is a bonus part for me to understand.

Comment: What if I need either: both x and y to be true, or y alone to be true, or z to be true?

Comment: `(x && y) || (y && !x) || z`, but again, here x would not matter, it could be simplified to `y || z`.

Comment: Lasse, thanks a lot again! The (y && !x) opens my mind a lot to the possibilities, and I'm still trying to wrap my mind around the insignificance of X in all this. Maybe I just have to check for X in its own statement.

Comment: "Maybe", but it is hard to know what you really want to do so I cannot answer that question.

Comment: @Rok just read it in plain english: "if x is true and y is true, or y is true and x is false"... is the same as saying "is y is true and x is true or false", which in turn makes x unnecesary, since it doesn't matter whether it's true or false, so it becomes "if y is true", you just read that loud :-)

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  It is valid syntax.

(I am assuming: (1) that x, y, and z are defined somewhere; and (2) "do this;" is pseudo-code for what you want to execute when the test passes.  `do` and `this` are both C# keywords, but this didn't seem like your intent)

**Update:** Added the fiddle source below

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        bool[] booleanDomain = new bool[]{ false, true };
        foreach(bool x in booleanDomain)
            foreach(bool y in booleanDomain)
                foreach(bool z in booleanDomain)
                    Test(x,y,z);

    }

    static void Test(bool x, bool y, bool z){
        bool result;
        if ( (x && y) || y || z) { 
            Console.WriteLine("the expression \"(x && y) || y || z\" is true when: \nx={0} \ny={1} \nz={2}\n", x, y, z);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Also - it looks like everyone else is telling you to compile and run it yourself.  In case that's not something that's easy for you to do with your setup https://dotnetfiddle.net/uT7Rqk

Comment: For the fiddle alone, +1. You should include it in the answer

Comment: smartcavenman, thank you; your assumption and understanding of my intent is correct.

Comment: And thank you for the fiddle link. You're right again; I'm not compiling, but editing an existing .cs file and have no idea of testing the validity, but with that link, maybe I can, if i understand it.

Answer (score 0):

Your question can be answered by studying better [opertors precedence and associativity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691323(v=vs.71).aspx). Anyway for boolean operation `&&` has higher precedence than `||`.
The expression you write is correct, if `x`,`y` and `z` are boolean variables. This is because c#, differently from C/C++ does not allow the conversion of any type to bool (ie anything different from zero, being true ), because C# uses just boolean expressions as argument in `if` conditions.